# SharePoint 2013 and integration with Office 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, office-integration

I have a fresh install of SharePoint Foundation 2013.  I'm about 99% finished configuring it, but I'm having problems with Office Integration.  My document library requires checkouts before editing.  I have two questions that I can't figure out:

1) When opening the document without checking it out, Microsoft Word displays an "Edit Document" button. Pressing it results in the message "We're having trouble connecting to the server. If this keeps happening contact your help desk.".  Using Fiddler, two http requests are made after clicking the button:

1. The first response is 401 Unauthorized
2. The second request sends the xml

   ```
   <D:lockinginfo...>...<D:lockinginfo>
   ```

The response is 403 Forbidden

Any ideas on how I can resolve this behavior so the user can initiate the edit client-side?

2) In previous versions of Office, the File tab contained a "Check-out" button and then a "Check-In" button. In Office 2013, I now only see an "Edit Document" button (which of course doesn't work). If I check out the document on the server and then download it, there does not appear to be a way to check it in from Word.  Clicking the Save button does upload the changes to the server, but the user would still have to go back to SharePoint to check it in.  Is this behavior a side-effect to the first problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.